# how to convert single character vector to numeric in R?

Tags: r

one column of my dataset looks like below;

```
"[3, 4, 5, 6]"
```

and I want to split every single value of this vector-like below as numeric;

```
3, 4, 5, 6
```

What can I do?

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: RegEx remove `[` and proceed as usual? e.g. `gsub("\\D","", vec)` (OK, this will drop the commas too)?

Comment: If you want to convert this to numeric, the output will be of list-col type.  Is that ok?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the brackets and split the string using the commas. `strsplit()` returns a list. You want a vector, so let us `unlist()` it and convert it to numerics.

```r
x <- "[3, 4, 5, 6]"
x <- gsub("\\[|\\]","", x)
y <- as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(x, ",", fixed=TRUE)))
y
#> [1] 3 4 5 6
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

For this vector

```
x = "[3, 4, 5, 6]"
```

find all matches of a sequence of 1 or more digits
and extract the matches from the original location

```
match = gregexpr("[[:digit:]]+", x)
values = regmatches(x, match)
```

This is a list of character values; coerce to integer, e.g., allowing `x` to be more than length 1

```
lapply(values, as.integer)
```